# NTP not working in ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS

Tags: 14.04, ntp

Is there any other way to sync my server close with external server. Some how NTP is not working in my Ubuntu server.

```
sudo ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org

no server suitable for synchronization found”
```

I tried this also but NTP service did not give any response.

```
seq 0 3 |xargs --replace ntpdate -p 1 -d {}.pool.ntp.org |grep receive
```

May be My ISP provide blocking NTP servers, I found this answer in this post.            [ntpdate " no server suitable for synchronization found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461305/ntpdate-no-server-suitable-for-synchronization-found)

Now i want know is there any other way to sync my system clock with external server.

Please let me know if any one have solution of my problem.

Comment: check whether ntp is installed in your machine else install with the command sudo apt-get install ntp. After doing so proceed with the step which you have done before.

Answer (score 0):

As your profile isn't complete, I can't tell you what servers to use for your country.

*However*, a bunch of ISPs block NTP access outside of their realm, so do a google search in your native language of "NTP countryname" and use those first.

If that doesn't help, drop a comment @Fabby below.

Comment: And as you're a reputation 1 user: don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, therefore "accepting" the answer, which is better then saying "thank you" as your and my reputation will go up...